# problemas realizar cast kotlin en "android"

Tags: android, kotlin

estoy intentando hacer "castings" en android  mendiante kotlin , como los hacia hace un par de meses..... pero me da error siempre, ¿sabeis si se trata de un bug?

yo hasta ahora hacia casting de este tipo y me funcionaban

```
var variable1:Int=12.11 as Int
var variable1=12.11 as Int
```

pero ahora hago este tipo de cast y me da error , no se si han cambiado algo o es un bug, he probado en ejecutarlo en API 26, 27, 28, y sigue dando error

Comment: Recuerda que puedes actualizar tu pregunta con esta información. No es necesario crear una respuesta, también está la opción de comentar. Sobre lo que dices, no creo que eso fuera posible en ningún momento, ya que Kotlin trabaja con clases, no con tipos primitivos. Por ende la forma correcta o válida de hacer lo que quieres, es la adjunta en mi respuesta. Incluso en C# que maneja una conversión similar, esto no es posible, quizás estés confundido. Incluso Kotlin mismo dice que ya no utiliza tipos primitivos, la cual es la unica manera de hacer esto posible en otros lenguajes como java o C#.

Comment: si, kotlin trabaja los datos primitivos "tradicionales" como objectos de una clase, pero te puedo asegurar que yo tenia  hecha esta conversion en un codigo que funcionaba  var resultado= variable1 as Int y ahora no me funciona, de ahi que mi conclusion sea que ahora estuviese bugueado, o que antes estuviese bugueado y lo hayan parcheado

Answer (score 4):

> No se puede hacer un `cast` directamente una clase `Double` a una clase `Int`. Además, `Double` e `Int` son objetos inmutables, por lo que no puedes modificarlos de ninguna manera.

Primitivamente, si se puede hacer el cast, pero en este caso se están manejando clases, por lo que si no guardan ninguna relación de herencia, es imposible hacer el `cast` porque te provocará una excepción.

En tu ejemplo tienes lo siguiente:

```
var variable1=12.11 as Int
```

Lo más que puedes hacer de esa manera es evitar la excepción y que te devuelva null con `as?` en vez de `as` en la conversión.

Según la [documentación oficial de Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-double/to-int.html) los valores marcados como Double puedes obtener el entero del mismo con la función `toInt()` por lo que en tu caso puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var variable1:Int = 12.11.toInt()
```

Todos los tipos o clases de representación numérica soportan los siguientes métodos:

```
toByte(): Byte
toShort(): Short
toInt(): Int
toLong(): Long
toFloat(): Float
toDouble(): Double
toChar(): Char
```

Puedes ver mas ejemplos en la [Documentación sobre los tipos basicos](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html).

Answer (score 1):

Hola aquí mi aportación olvidate de los `cast` y los `findViewById` en Kotlin solo necesitas añadir el siguiente `import`:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity nombre del paquete.*
```

Con eso podremos llamar directamente  a botones ,barras,etc... y usar sus metodos mediante su id sin tener que castear ni tener que usar el `findViewById`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas intentando hacer es que un valor de tipo **FLOAT** Números racionales, ejemplos: 1f, 1.01, 2.0001. sea almacenado en una variable de tipo **INT** Números enteros, que solo admite valores enteros ejemplos: 1, 2, 3... lo que te recomiendo hacer es dejarle la responsabilidad de elegir el tipo de variable a kotlin, que es capaz de hacerlo a diferencia de java

```
var variable1 = 1.11
```

Hacer esto te permitirá utilizarla del modo que requieras.

Pero si quiere eliminar la parte racional del valor y permitir al mismo ser almacenado en una variable de tipo INT puede intentar con esto.

```
var variable1 = (1.11).toInt()
```